# How to show Alert dialog when i go from one activity to other?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-alertdialog, startactivityforresult

I have 2 Activities, I want to show Alert dialog when I move from Activity B to Activity A.

This is how I go from one activity to other.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_B.this,
    Activity_A.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Now when I reach Activity_A, I want to show the alert dialog below.

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setMessage(context.getString(R.string.xxxx));
    builder.setPositiveButton(context.getString(R.string.ok_button), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });
    alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Where should i put this dialog?

**EDITED MY QUESTION:-**

Here is My Flow

Activity A > Activity B (10 fragments) > Activity A

Now When i move from Activity B to Activity A , after Activity A launches I want to show alert dialog.
Note : Only when I move from Activity B to Activity A.

Comment: if you want to show the dialog in the new activity when it starts, why not show the dialog in the onCreate/onResume of the destination activity?

Comment: Activity A is my landing screen on my app. So If i put it in onCreate/onResume then the dialog will be called each time I launch my app.

Comment: "So If i put it in onCreate/onResume then the dialog will be called each time I launch my app" - yes it will be show. If you want to show only once/first-time use saved SharedPreference Boolean value to determine.

Comment: Can you give me a example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally found a way, Thanks for the answers.**

**The reason I was always wrong before was I was using startActivtyResult in Activity_B and tried to launch Alert dialog in it. This way**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_B.this,
    Activity_A.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivityForResult(intent,2);
```

**This is the correct way :**

From Activity_A i called Activity_B this way :

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_A.this, Activity_B.class);
               map.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
               startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
```

And in OnActivityResult of Activity_A :

```
  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 2) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
          AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
          builder.setMessage(context.getString(R.string.xxxx));
          builder.setPositiveButton(context.getString(R.string.ok_button),            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });
           alertDialog = builder.create();
           alertDialog.show();
}
        }
```

And in Activity_B I'm just calling Activity_A this way:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        setResult(Activity_A.RESULT_OK, intent);

        finish();
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, I just simply put like this then the dialog will come out

```
  public class AddItem extends Activity {
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_item);

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage(context.getString(R.string.xxxx));
            builder.setPositiveButton(context.getString(R.string.ok_button), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });
    alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`Activity#getCallingActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getCallingActivity()) to determine whether Activity A was opened by Activity B, and wrap your Dialog logic around that check.

However, this requires you use [`startActivityForResult`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)) to open Activity A.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what your looking for. Override the method on start of the activity you want to display the dialog. Hope it helps.

```
@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    //Your Dialog here
}
```